# Querying a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to do two things:

1. query an attribute from an inner join table in Rails' Console.
2. query and displaying the attribute in a view.

These are my Models:

`retreat.rb`:

```
class Retreat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :retreats_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :retreats_teams
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :retreats_teams
end
```

`retreats_team.rb`:

```
class RetreatsTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :retreat
end
```

`team.rb`:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_members

  has_many :retreats
  has_many :retreats, through: :retreats_teams
end
```

In Rails' console, if I type:

```
Retreat.last.teams
```

I get the output:

```
irb(main):008:0> Retreat.last.teams
  Retreat Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "retreats".* FROM "retreats" ORDER BY "retreats"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Team Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "retreats_teams" ON "teams"."id" = "retreats_teams"."team_id" WHERE "retreats_teams"."retreat_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["retreat_id", 38], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Team id: 56, name: "My house", account_id: 2, created_at: "2020-02-10 15:57:25", updated_at: "2020-02-10 15:57:25">]>
irb(main):009:0>
```

How do I retrieve the team name: "My house"?

Also, there might be many teams that display here, too.

Comment: `Retreat.last.teams.first.name`? I'm not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: `Retreat.last.teams.first.name?` returns true. I am trying to return the name itself, which in the case provided the name is name: "My house"

Comment: Well, question mark is not part of the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#teams` returns a collection of team objects. The simplest solution is to call `first` on the teams to get the first team in the collection:

```
Retreat.last.teams.first.name

=> "My house"
```

But if you want all the names in `teams` you might use `pluck`. This will allow you to do this:

```
retreat = Retreat.last
foo = Team.create(name: 'Foo')
bar = Team.create(name: 'Bar')
retreat.teams << foo
retreat.teams << bar

retreat.teams.pluck(:name).to_sentence

=> "My house, Foo, and Bar"
```

Comment: Pluck only really makes sense though if you only want the name. If your doing the common task of for example creating a list of links its worthless as you need the id as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### A word on naming

The naming convention for join models is `SingularSingular`. The table should be named `singular_plural`. `has_and_belongs_to_many` is the only part of Rails that actually uses the oddball `plural_plural` naming scheme.

```
RetreatsTeam  # bad
RetreatTeam   # better
```

Even better though is to actually give your join tables meaningful names instead of just placeholder names.

> 1) querying an attribute from an inner join table in Rails Console.

Since the association between Retreat and RetreatsTeams in one to many you can actually only fetch aggregates. Otherwise which attribute should it fetch, from the first row, the last row or all the rows?

So for example you can do:

```
Retreat.joins(:retreats_teams)
       .select('retreats.*', 'COUNT(retreats_teams.*) AS retreats_teams_count')
```

If you are storing more data on the join table that you want to display you want to iterate through the join table:

```
@retreat = Retreat.eager_load(retreats_teams: :teams).first
@retreat.retreats_teams.each do |rt|
  puts rt.foo
  puts rt.team.name
end
```

> 2) querying and displaying the attribute in a view.

In Rails you're usually just fetching records in the controller and then iterating through them in the view:

```
class ResortsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @resort = Resort.includes(:teams).find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/views/resorts/show.html.erb
<h1><%= @resort.name %></h1>
<h2>Teams</h2>
<% if @resort.teams.any? %>
  <ul>
  <% @resort.teams.each do |team| %>
    <li><%= team.name %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>This resort has no teams</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the note/answers. And yes, I agree that the naming convention is off for RetreatsTeam. Planning to update this to be singular